# Visual Studio go to bookmark only inside current file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to go to the next/prev bookmark only inside the current file? I'm using VS 2010 and I find it extremly annoying that it jumps always across all files when I want to navigate inside the current file only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Go to "customize" (right click on the toolbox area, choose customize) ->commands->keyboard, choose edit.NextBookmarkInDocument and associate it with a shortcut.
In addition, you can add it as a button in the text editor toolbar. Go to to text editor toolbar, press the little mark on the bottom-right,and choose the appropriate button to add.

Comment: In newer VS it's Customize -> Toolbars -> Keyboard button on bottom right

Answer (score 0):

Set bookmarks to stay in one file in Visual Studio 2019

In the Search box at the very top menu, put in ‘customize’ and hit Enter’.
A complex box comes up, but I simply clicked on a button at the bottom labelled ‘Keyboard’, which is where keyboard shortcuts can be set up.

That brings up another huge box. In the left hand pane is Environment and under that is Keyboard. I guess that the way I went in is why this was expanded and already selected, so there must be other ways to get to the same place.
In a right hand pane is now a huge list of commands that can have shortcuts attached!

The ones to scroll to (enlarge the box or the scroll bar is a joke. A slight move scrolls dozens of lines!) are Edit.NextBookmarkInDocument and Edit.PreviousBookmarkInDocument. (similar commands without ‘inDocument on the end are what f2/ shift f2 do by default and jumps between files rather than staying in the same document.)

When you select a command you can then just click on the field labelled ‘Press shortcut keys’ and then press the keys you want to be the shortcut for that command.

I assigned Edit.NextBookmarkInDocument to f2, which then replaces the old f2 that jumps from file to file, and shift f2 for Edit.PreviousBookmarkInDocument. You have to press the ‘Assign’ button to make VS remember the change.  After this, bookmark jumps stay in the same file. I guess you could choose any shortcut you fancy, and it does at least show you if that shortcut is assigned and what it is assigned to.

There are some features which I have not explored, like when I use f2 it shows it is assigned to ‘Rename’ but it seems to not effect that function at all when you reassign and just takes it away from the jump between files command version. Maybe someone would like to delve deeper, but what I did worked without any side effects and renames outside of VS still worked with f2 so I have no idea what it was going on about.